# Nexus 5X Nethunter has no linux-headers for 3.10.73-Re4son-3.5

Tags: linux

So, i rooted my Nexus 5X oreo 8.1, installed nethunter, all good so far. I bought an tp-link TL-WN722N v3(EU) and now i'm trying to make it work. I downloaded the drivers from tp-link website but i can't install them because when i use command 'make' it's say:
`/lib/modules/3.10.73-Re4son-3.5/build: No such file or directory.`

If i install linux-headers with:
`apt-get install linux-headers-$(umane -r)`
It's say: `E:Unable to locate package`

How can i install the Linux-headers  for rtl8188eu drivers?
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `uname -a` then use the full name of the `linux-headers-$VERSION`.

You can get the available `linux-headers` through:

```
apt search linux-headers
```

Then intsall it:

```
sudo apt install linux-heasers-$VERSION
```

Comment: Afer I type `sudo apt install linux-heasers-$VERSION` it's say:
`Package 'linux-headers' is not installed, so not removed.`

My uname -a: `Linux kali 3.10.73-Re4son-3.5 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Apr 10 12:20:30 AEST 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux`